# Passing a compiled Expression to Linq To NHibernate

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate, expression-trees

I have a collection of compiled expressions which I combined into one expression because I want to build dynamically my linq query. See [ExpressionTree Compile() method generate a stackoverflow exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14144510/expressiontree-compile-method-generate-a-stackoverflow-exception)  for the reason I used compiled expression in order to prevent from stackoverflow because in my computer when the query contains more than 7000 expressions, it throws this exception.)
Then I use the new generated expression and pass it to my FindAll method. Problem, NHibernate is not able to execute the query and says:

unable to cast object of type 'nhibernate.hql.ast.parameter' to type 'nhibernate.hql.ast.hqlbooleanexpression'

```
public IList<T> FindAll(Expression<Func<T, bool>> criteria)
{
     return SessionFactory.GetCurrentSession()
                          .QueryOver<T>()
                          .Where(criteria)
                          .List();
}
```

I debuged and found that nhibernate tries to convert the compiled expression to boolean expression in file HqlTreeNode (method: HqlTreeNodeExtensions.AsBooleanExpression(this HqlTreeNode node) which of course doesn't works. Then what solution should I use ?

Here what the criteria variable looks like:

```
(Invoke(value(System.Func`2[Something.SomeEntity,System.Boolean]) // this don't work
```

For information, if it wasn't compiled, it would have looked like something like this:

```
([someEntity].UserID == 1) // this works
```

Thank you.

Comment: A compiled expression is basically MSIL code in a dynamic assembly. NHiberate doesn't know how to make heads or tails out of compiled code, so it needs expressions to walk the expression tree. I would try to fix the problem of having 7,000 expressions, not trying to use a compiled expression.

Comment: you're right, I should put my effort to reduce the number of expressions. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @vcsjones Maybe you want to post that as an answer?

Comment: @JohnSmith There may be some way to let NHibernate process your 7000 expressions (though I'm not sure how exactly), but I think the generated SQL would be very slow.

Comment: Looking at your previous question, you might be able to consolidate your expressions to a set of `int[]{1,2,3,4,5,6,7}.Any(i => i == [someEntity].UserId)`, these would be converted to an `in` or `exists` statement.